# Таблица в Android Studio

Tags: android, tableview

как можно реализовать такой View в Andoid Studio? Имею ввиду эту таблицу с текстом и картинкой. Заранее очень благодарен[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через CardView.

Comment: Похоже на RecyclerView + GridLayoutManager

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я сделал через RecyclerView и Grid и достиг желаемого результата!